# How do I tell if a file does not exist in Bash?

Tags: bash, file-io, scripting

This checks if a file exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1     
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "File $FILE exists."
else
   echo "File $FILE does not exist."
fi
```

How do I only check if the file does **not** exist?

Comment: I've found this [list of bash conditional statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) very useful.

Comment: Being the very lazy person that I am, I would typically have used the following silly workaround construct: `if [ -f $FILE ]; then; else; echo "File $FILE does not exist."; fi;` Probably good that I found this question instead and learned to do it in a more proper way. :)

Comment: To be pendantic, you should say "regular file", as most UNIX/POSIX docs refer generically to all types of file system entries a simply "files", e.g., a symbolic link is a type of a file, as is a named pipe, regular file, directory, block special, character special, socket, etc.

Comment: @kevinarpe if you want to test whether _something_ exists, use `-e`. -f won't pick up directories, symlinks, etc.

Comment: To be safe, always use double quotes to correctly handle file names with whitespace, e.g., `FILE=$1` -> `FILE="$1"` and `if [ -f $FILE ];` -> `if [ -f "$FILE" ];`

Comment: Unfortunately this is prone for race conditions and not useful in most use cases, except of trivial hello world examples.

Comment: As a side note and regarding your "$FILE" variable: By convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: How do I check if certain files exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572206/bash-how-do-i-check-if-certain-files-exist)

Comment: @jww This is the opposite of that question. This is asking for specific syntax.

Answer (score 5388, accepted):

The [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) command (written as `[` here) has a "not" logical operator, `!` (exclamation mark):

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
fi
```

Comment: More succinctly: [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ] && echo "File not found!"

Comment: I struggled a bit to find the right syntax for "if any of 2 files does not exist". The following both work:
`if [ ! \( -f "f1" -a -f "f2" \) ] ; then echo MISSING; fi`
`if [ ! -f "f1" ] || [ ! -f "f2" ] ; then echo MISSING; fi`

Comment: @DavidWinterbottom Even more succulently: `[ -f /tmp/foo.txt ] || echo "File not found!"`

Comment: Parameter can be any one of the following:
`-e: Returns true value, if file exists`
`-f: Return true value, if file exists and regular file`
`-r: Return true value, if file exists and is readable`
`-w: Return true value, if file exists and is writable`
`-x: Return true value, if file exists and is executable` 
`-d: Return true value, if exists and is a directory`

Comment: If you want to use 2 conditions in an if-operation, use the -a operator, this means AND. I think this is also possible with & if you use the [[ ]] operator

Comment: There is an asymmetry in using `! -f` with `&&` versus using `-f` with `||`. This has to do with the exit code returned by the non/existence check. If you need your line to always exit cleanly with exit code 0 (and sometimes you don't want this constraint), the two approaches are not interchangeable. Alternatively, just use an `if` statement and you no longer have to worry about the exit code of your non/existence check.

Comment: if the file name is dynamic, test it with `if [ ! -f "$filename" ]; then...` because it might contain spaces

Comment: Used this to only run a cron job if the script exists, since our cron tasks deploy out before our app code base
`* * * * * [ -f foo.php] && php foo.php`

Comment: [[ is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the [ command. See <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031> and <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals>. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, it is recommend to use [[.

Comment: Keep a `space` between `[` and `!`, it will not work otherwise

Comment: I propose `[[ ! -f ... ]]; then`. Why you are not using double brackets? - - I cannot get your proposal work.

Comment: In the text `echo "File not found!"` just replace double quotes for single quotes, otherwise you may get `bash: !": event not found`

Comment: How do I provide an array of filename like if I want to check if any of the `11?.out` or `22?.out` exists?

Answer (score 933):

**Bash File Testing**

`-b filename` - Block special file
`-c filename` - Special character file
`-d directoryname` - Check for directory Existence
`-e filename` - Check for file existence, regardless of type (node, directory, socket, symlink, etc.)
`-f filename` - Check for regular file existence not a directory
`-G filename` - Check if file exists and is owned by effective group ID
`-G filename set-group-id` - True if file exists and is set-group-id
`-k filename` - Sticky bit
`-L filename` - Symbolic link
`-O filename` - True if file exists and is owned by the effective user id
`-r filename` - Check if file is a readable
`-S filename` - Check if file is socket
`-s filename` - Check if file is nonzero size
`-u filename` - Check if file set-user-id bit is set
`-w filename` - Check if file is writable
`-x filename` - Check if file is executable

**How to use:**

```
#!/bin/bash
file=./file
if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    echo "File exists"
else 
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

A *test expression* can be negated by using the `!` operator

```
#!/bin/bash
file=./file
if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
    echo "File does not exist"
else 
    echo "File exists"
fi
```

Comment: @0x90 If you want, you are free to edit my post and add it to the list. I guess you mean: `-n String` - Check if the length of the string isn't zero. Or do you mean `file1 -nt file2` - Check if file1 is newer then file 2 (you can also use -ot for older then)

Comment: About -n:  `The unary operator -z tests for a null string, while -n or no operator at all returns True if a string is not empty.` ~ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html

Comment: why didn't some add a function like   function exists() {                                                                                                                                                                                                               ⏎
   if [ -e "$1" ]; then
       echo "$1 exists"
   else
       echo "$1 does not exist"
   fi
}

Comment: @MzA because we need to make the code readable, nobody knows what is $1. So assign $1 as `file` and then use that `file` variable to do something else looks more readable than using an unknown argument `$1`

Comment: Regarding the `-G` operator, the two are slightly different, as I understand it. going by the "SETUID & SETGID BITS" section of the `chmod` man-page, the two would give different values in the case of root user, would they not. I am referring specifically to the "unless user has appropriate permissions" part. Regardless, excellent answer. Bookmarking for this alone.

Answer (score 342):

Negate the expression inside `test` (for which `[` is an alias) using `!`:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]
then
    echo "File $FILE does not exist"
fi
```

The relevant man page is `man test` or, equivalently, `man [` -- or `help test` or `help [` for the built-in bash command.

Alternatively (less commonly used) you can negate the result of `test` using:

```
if ! [ -f "$FILE" ]
then
    echo "File $FILE does not exist"
fi
```

That syntax is described in "man 1 bash" in sections "**Pipelines**" and "**Compound Commands**".

Comment: In [tag:bash], `[` is a builtin. So the relevant information is rather obtained by `help [`... but this shows that `[` is a synonym for the `test` builtin, hence the relevant information is rather obtained by `help test`. See also the [Bash Conditional Expression section in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yes, but the bash built-in `[` command behaves very similarly to the external `[` command, so either `man test` or `man [` will give you a good idea of how it works.

Comment: @KeithThompson except that the _bash_ builtin `[` has more switches than the external command `[` found on my system... Generally speaking I believe it's better to read the documentation specific to a given tool, and not the documentation specific to another vaguely related one. I might be wrong, though `;)`

Answer (score 156):

```
[[ -f $FILE ]] || printf '%s does not exist!\n' "$FILE"
```

Also, it's possible that the file is a broken symbolic link, or a non-regular file, like e.g. a socket, device or fifo. For example, to add a check for broken symlinks:

```
if [[ ! -f $FILE ]]; then
    if [[ -L $FILE ]]; then
        printf '%s is a broken symlink!\n' "$FILE"
    else
        printf '%s does not exist!\n' "$FILE"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: May I ask why the two "["s in the test? (eg [[ ! -a $FILE ]]). I tried all the options mentioned on a solaris box and only that one worked, so grateful, but why?

Comment: Double brackets are a "modern" extension; eg they won't do word splitting (such as for filenames with spaces) and still work for empty strings: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: according to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html -a is identical in effect to -e. It has been "deprecated," and its use is discouraged. Anyhow +1 for mentioning to check on broken symlink too

Comment: @dimitrismistriotis two "[" is a non-portable extension implemented (differently) by zsh & bash; generally you should avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: See [SO 321348](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321348/bash-if-a-vs-e-option) for a good reason why `-a` can't be negated in single bracket conditional expressions.  Avoid `-a` altogether, I suggest.

Comment: Changed this around a bit to eliminate `-a`, but also because `-a` is equivalent to `-e`, which returns true for an existing file regardless of type, you'd run into trouble if adding checks for fifos or sockets in the second example.

Answer (score 118):

It's worth mentioning that if you need to execute a single command you can abbreviate

```
if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

to

```
test -f "$file" || echo "$file"
```

or

```
[ -f "$file" ] || echo "$file"
```

Comment: Thanks! Needed an alternative that does not use [[ ]]

Comment: That's called short-circuit evaluation, is it? It works because of lazy evaluation, if `A` is true, `B` is irrelevant in `A || B`

Answer (score 83):

I prefer to do the following one-liner, in [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell compatible format:

```
$ [ -f "/$DIR/$FILE" ] || echo "$FILE NOT FOUND"

$ [ -f "/$DIR/$FILE" ] && echo "$FILE FOUND"
```

For a couple of commands, like I would do in a script:

```
$  [ -f "/$DIR/$FILE" ] || { echo "$FILE NOT FOUND" ; exit 1 ;}
```

Once I started doing this, I rarely use the fully typed syntax anymore!!

Comment: First of all, unquoted variable references are error-prone. That said, where does it say in *any* bash manpage that the `[` or `test` built-in would test for *file existence* of the argument by default (as opposed to `-e`)? Would that not be ambiguous? AFAIK (and AIUI the section "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS") the only thing that is tested with your approach is that the argument is not empty (or undefined), which is, in this case, a tautology (let `$DIR = ''` and `$FILE = ''`, then the argument is still `'//'`).

Comment: Proof: `ls /foo`, result `ls: cannot access /foo: No such file or directory`. `[ /foo ] && echo 42`, result `42`. GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: @PointedEars: I failed to specify the `-f` option, at the moment I wrote this answer.  Obviously you could always use `-e`, if your not sure it will be a regular file.  Additionally In all my scripts I quote these constructs, I must have just submitted this without adequate proofing.

Comment: ACK. But you probably know that a one-liner cannot solve the if-else problem: `[ $condition ] && if_true || if_false` is error-prone. In any event, I find `[ ! -f "$file" ] && if_not_exists` easier to read and understand than `[ -f "$file" ] || if_not_exists`.

Answer (score 67):

To test file existence, the parameter can be any one of the following:

```
-e: Returns true if file exists (regular file, directory, or symlink)
-f: Returns true if file exists and is a regular file
-d: Returns true if file exists and is a directory
-h: Returns true if file exists and is a symlink
```

All the tests below apply to regular files, directories, and symlinks:

```
-r: Returns true if file exists and is readable
-w: Returns true if file exists and is writable
-x: Returns true if file exists and is executable
-s: Returns true if file exists and has a size > 0
```

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
   echo "File $FILE exists"
else
   echo "File $FILE does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 53):

You can do this:

```
[[ ! -f "$FILE" ]] && echo "File doesn't exist"
```

or

```
if [[ ! -f "$FILE" ]]; then
    echo "File doesn't exist"
fi
```

If you want to check for file and folder both, then use `-e` option instead of `-f`. `-e` returns true for regular files, directories, socket, character special files, block special files etc.

Comment: That is not bash-specific. The syntax comes from the Korn shell and is also available in zsh and bash. It has limited advantage over the standard `[` utility here though.

Comment: _regular_ files (as checked by `-f`) and _directories_ are just two of many different types of _files_. There are also sockets, symlinks, devices, fifos, doors... `[ -e` will test for file existence (of any type including regular, fifo, directory...) _after symlink resolution_.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : I don't see any ksh or zsh tag anywhere. We are talking about bash or something that is standardized on most unix systems. So, within the context, it's bash specific. OP doesn't need to know of every whatever shells are out there :D

Comment: That was a comment on the _"Bash specific"_ part of your answer.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : Yes, and within context (bash and the standard sh), it's bash specific. I don't see the point in your second comment, it's totally out of context. OP doesn't need `-e`, he needs `-f`.

Comment: @Jahid, to call a general construct specific to only a certain utility is just wrong- because it's not Bash specific. If one can use it in ksh, then it's simply not contrained to this utility. The fact that it's being discussed under this topic is not license to say, "By the way, now that we're talking about Bash, let me introduce you to something that's specific to Bash." No- it's just not. -1 for being misleading in a technical forum. If you were writing about Python, would you say, "Now let me introduce you to this amazing Python-specific concept: The `if` statement." ? I don't think so.

Comment: ...You also miss the mark with your comment about `-e`. As Stephane says, `-e` returns true for almost any entity in the filesystem: fifos, directories, regular files, block special files, character special files, etc. Your answer appears to suggest that you're simply expanding a little bit on `-f` and adding directories to its match against regular files. You're not; it's much more broad than that.

Answer (score 44):

You should be careful about running `test` for an unquoted variable, because it might produce unexpected results:

```
$ [ -f ]
$ echo $?
0
$ [ -f "" ]
$ echo $?
1
```

The recommendation is usually to have the tested variable surrounded by double quotation marks:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=$1

if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]
then
   echo "File $FILE does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: The recommendation is to have **every** variable surrounded by double quotation marks, unless you know exactly that you have one of the rare cases where it's unnecessary, or one of the even rarer cases where it's harmful. (And no, this is not one of them.)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why this is not the case to use double quotation mark? Otherwise I don't see the usefulness in the comment.

Comment: I meant: This is not one of the rare cases where it's unnecessary or harmful. A shell programmer should get used to enclose (almost) every variable in double quotes; this rule is not limited to `[ ... ]`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Answer (score 32):

In

```
[ -f "$file" ]
```

the `[` command does a `stat()` (not `lstat()`) system call on the path stored in `$file` and returns *true* if that system call succeeds and the type of the file as returned by `stat()` is "*regular*".

So if `[ -f "$file" ]` returns true, you can tell the file does exist and is a regular file or a symlink eventually resolving to a regular file (or at least it was at the time of the `stat()`).

However if it returns *false* (or if `[ ! -f "$file" ]` or `! [ -f "$file" ]` return true), there are many different possibilities:

- the file doesn't exist
- the file exists but is not a *regular* file (could be a device, fifo, directory, socket...)
- the file exists but you don't have search permission to the parent directory
- the file exists but that path to access it is too long
- the file is a symlink to a regular file, but you don't have search permission to some of the directories involved in the resolution of the symlink.
- ... any other reason why the `stat()` system call may fail.

In short, it should be:

```
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
  printf '"%s" is a path to a regular file or symlink to regular file\n' "$file"
elif [ -e "$file" ]; then
  printf '"%s" exists but is not a regular file\n' "$file"
elif [ -L "$file" ]; then
  printf '"%s" exists, is a symlink but I cannot tell if it eventually resolves to an actual file, regular or not\n' "$file"
else
  printf 'I cannot tell if "%s" exists, let alone whether it is a regular file or not\n' "$file"
fi
```

To know for sure that the file doesn't exist, we'd need the `stat()` system call to return with an error code of `ENOENT` (`ENOTDIR` tells us one of the path components is not a directory is another case where we can tell the file doesn't exist by that path). Unfortunately the `[` command doesn't let us know that. It will return false whether  the error code is ENOENT, EACCESS (permission denied), ENAMETOOLONG or anything else.

The `[ -e "$file" ]` test can also be done with `ls -Ld -- "$file" > /dev/null`. In that case, `ls` will tell you why the `stat()` failed, though the information can't easily be used programmatically:

```
$ file=/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
$ if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then echo does not exist; fi
does not exist
$ if ! ls -Ld -- "$file" > /dev/null; then echo stat failed; fi
ls: cannot access '/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root': Permission denied
stat failed
```

At least `ls` tells me it's not because the file doesn't exist that it fails. It's because it can't tell whether the file exists or not. The `[` command just ignored the problem.

With the `zsh` shell, you can query the error code with the `$ERRNO` special variable after the failing `[` command, and decode that number using the `$errnos` special array in the `zsh/system` module:

```
zmodload zsh/system
ERRNO=0
if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
  err=$ERRNO
  case $errnos[err] in
    ("") echo exists, not a regular file;;
    (ENOENT|ENOTDIR)
       if [ -L "$file" ]; then
         echo broken link
       else
         echo does not exist
       fi;;
    (*) syserror -p "can't tell: " "$err"
  esac
fi
```

(beware the [`$errnos` support was broken with some versions of `zsh` when built with recent versions of `gcc`](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01696.html)).

Answer (score 25):

There are three distinct ways to do this:

1. Negate the exit status with bash (no other answer has said this):

   ```
   if ! [ -e "$file" ]; then
       echo "file does not exist"
   fi
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   ! [ -e "$file" ] && echo "file does not exist"
   ```
2. Negate the test inside the test command `[` (that is the way most answers before have presented):

   ```
   if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
       echo "file does not exist"
   fi
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   [ ! -e "$file" ] && echo "file does not exist"
   ```
3. Act on the result of the test being negative (`||` instead of `&&`):

   Only:

   ```
   [ -e "$file" ] || echo "file does not exist"
   ```

   This looks silly (IMO), don't use it unless your code has to be portable to the Bourne shell (like the `/bin/sh` of Solaris 10 or earlier) that lacked the pipeline negation operator (`!`):

   ```
   if [ -e "$file" ]; then
       :
   else
       echo "file does not exist"
   fi
   ```

Comment: Any portability difference between `! [` and `[ !`?

Comment: The `! [` [is POSIX for shell pipelines 2.9.2 (any command)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) `Otherwise, the exit status shall be the logical NOT of the exit status of the last command` and `[ ! ` [is POSIX for test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128) `!  expression True if expression is false. False if expression is true.` So, both are POSIX, and in my experience, both are extensively supported.

Comment: @FrozenFlame, the Bourne shell didn't have the `!` keyword which was introduced by the Korn shell. Except maybe for Solaris 10 and older, you're unlikely to come across a Bourne shell these days though.

Answer (score 18):

```
envfile=.env

if [ ! -f "$envfile" ]
then
    echo "$envfile does not exist"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 12):

To reverse a test, use "!".
That is equivalent to the "not" logical operator in other languages. Try this:

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ];
then
    echo "File not found!"
fi
```

Or written in a slightly different way:

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ]
    then echo "File not found!"
fi
```

Or you could use:

```
if ! [ -f /tmp/foo.txt ]
    then echo "File not found!"
fi
```

Or, presing all together:

```
if ! [ -f /tmp/foo.txt ]; then echo "File not found!"; fi
```

Which may be written (using then "and" operator: &&) as:

```
[ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ] && echo "File not found!"
```

Which looks shorter like this:

```
[ -f /tmp/foo.txt ] || echo "File not found!"
```

Answer (score 10):

The `test` thing may count too. It worked for me (based on *[Bash Shell: Check File Exists or Not](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-existence-of-file-in-bash/)*):

```
test -e FILENAME && echo "File exists" || echo "File doesn't exist"
```

Comment: Where is something *counted* in this answer?

Comment: @U.Windl I don't understand

Comment: "the `test` thing may count too.": What does it count?

Comment: @U.Windl According to the edit, it's not me who wrote it. I wrote "does the next thing count too? it worked for me (based on [this link][1]) :"  . In this matter, the "count" means "work".

Answer (score 10):

This code also working .

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
if [ -f $FILE ]; then
 echo "File '$FILE' Exists"
else
 echo "The File '$FILE' Does Not Exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way

```
FILE=$1
[ ! -e "${FILE}" ] && echo "does not exist" || echo "exists"
```

Answer (score 6):

This shell script also works for finding a file in a directory:

```
echo "enter file"

read -r a

if [ -s /home/trainee02/"$a" ]
then
    echo "yes. file is there."
else
    echo "sorry. file is not there."
fi
```

Comment: It isn't clear that this adds anything that other answers have not already given.  It hard-codes a pathname.  Since the question is tagged [tag:bash], it could use `read -p "Enter file name: " -r a` to prompt as well as read.  It does use quotes around the variable; that's good, but should be explained.  It might be better if it echoed the file name.  And this checks that the file exists and is not empty (that's the meaning of `-s`) whereas the question asks about any file, empty or not (for which `-f` is more appropriate).

Answer (score 6):

sometimes it may be handy to use && and || operators.

Like in (if you have command "test"):

```
test -b $FILE && echo File not there!
```

or

```
test -b $FILE || echo File there!
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also group multiple commands in the one liner

`[ -f "filename" ] || ( echo test1 && echo test2 && echo test3 )`

or

`[ -f "filename" ] || { echo test1 && echo test2 && echo test3 ;}`

If filename doesn't exit, the output will be

```
test1
test2
test3
```

[Note](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606378/when-to-use-vs-in-bash): ( ... ) runs in a subshell, { ... ;} runs in the same shell.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `test` instead of `[]`, then you can use `!` to get the negation:

```
if ! test "$FILE"; then
  echo "does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! I was scrolling endless looking/hoping someone would provide this version :-)

Comment: You can use `!` even when using `[`!