# How can I check a file exists and execute a command if not?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a daemon I have written using Python. When it is running, it has a PID file located at `/tmp/filename.pid`. If the daemon isn't running then PID file doesn't exist.

On Linux, how can I check to ensure that the PID file exists and if not, execute a command to restart it?

The command would be

```
python daemon.py restart
```

which has to be executed from a specific directory.

Comment: The "which has to be executed from a specific directory" part of your description sounds like a recipe for trouble.  Beware - rethink if at all possible.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-file-does-not-exist-in-bash/

Comment: /tmp is a bad location to put PID files, since some distributions have cleaner processes that delete files from /tmp, and users may delete files from there to make space.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
[ -f /tmp/filename.pid ] || python daemon.py restart
```

`-f` checks if the given path exists and is a regular file (just `-e` checks if the path exists)

the `[]` perform the test and returns `0` on success, `1` otherwise

the `||` is a C-like `or`, so if the command on the left fails, execute the command on the right.

So the final statement says, if `/tmp/filename.pid` does NOT exist then start the daemon.

Comment: What do you mean by "regular file"? What are the other options?

Comment: @Barakuda - A non-regular file could be a directory, named pipe, network socket, character device, symbolic link...

Comment: Must be && instead of ||

Comment: I think && is if the condition is met, while || is if it's not met. 

[ -f my_file ] || echo 'absent' && echo 'exists'

Answer (score 19):

```
test -f filename && daemon.py restart || echo "File doesn't exists"
```

Comment: if only the file needs to be checked for existence : test -f filename && echo "exists" || echo "does not exist"

Answer (score 11):

If it is bash scripting you are wondering about, something like this would work:

```
if [ ! -f "$FILENAME" ]; then
   python daemon.py restart
fi
```

A better option may be to look into [lockfile](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile)

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are fine for detecting the existence of the file. However for a complete solution you probably should check that the PID in the pidfile is still running, and that it's your program.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to solving the problem is a script that ensures that your daemon "stays" alive...

Something like this (note: signal handling should be added for proper startup/shutdown):

```
$PIDFILE = "/path/to/pidfile"

if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ]; then
    echo "Pid file exists!"
    exit 1
fi

while true; do
    # Write it's own pid file
    python your-server.py ;

    # force removal of pid in case of unexpected death.
    rm -f $PIDFILE;

    # sleep for 2 seconds
    sleep 2;

done
```

In this way, the server will stay alive even if it dies unexpectedly.

Comment: `if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ]; then` should actually be `if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ]; then`. I tried to edit it, but the edit is too small for stackoverflow. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a ready solution like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Answer (score 1):

```
ls /tmp/filename.pid
```

It returns true if file exists. Returns false if file does not exist.