# Execute command only if file exists

Tags: bash

I have a command:

```
dwebp /home/user/1/input.webp -o /home/user/2/output.png
```

What should I add to execute this command only if `input.webp` exists?

Comment: The question has already beenn answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669675/how-can-i-check-a-file-exists-and-execute-a-command-if-not)

Comment: @ArturoSeijas that link is not the answer, there's no clear explanation on how to run it the other way around (i.e. if the file DOES exist). I was confused and reached here, so yeah... the question is still pretty relevant

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that validates that, and executes the command only if that file exists in the filesystem.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ -f /home/user/1/input.webp ]; then
   dwebp /home/user/1/input.webp -o /home/user/2/output.png
fi
```