# How to check if a file exists on a server with bash

Tags: bash, shell

Checking if a [file exists on my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-file-does-not-exist-in-bash) is easy. But how about checking if this file exist on my server?

If my file is:

```
host@server:/path/to/my/file.txt
```

What do I need to do to check if it exists?

Comment: You might want to look at the manual page for `ssh`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this?

```
ssh user@host 'if [ -f /path/to/my/file.txt ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi'
```

Comment: I found some thing like this, but this work very fine. I found my error. I use ssh user@host:/path/to/my/ 'if [ -f file.txt ]; ... This not work :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could help -

```
ping -c 1 ipaddress && ssh user@host 'test -e /path/and/filename && echo exists'
```

Comment: Work to. A little more verbose :)

Comment: Just to check if the host is up or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh serverName

test -e
echo $?
```