# Check if file exists and continue else exit in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, continue

I have a script that is one script in a chain of others that sends an email.

At the start of the script I want to check if a file exists and continue only if it exists, otherwise just quit.

Here is the start of my script:

```
if [ ! -f /scripts/alert ];
then
    echo "File not found!" && exit 0
else
        continue
fi
```

However I keep getting a message saying:

```
line 10: continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Why do you need the 'continue' at all here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell if a regular file does not exist in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
{
if [ ! -f /scripts/alert ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
    exit 0
fi
}
```

A conditional isn't a loop, and there's no place you need to jump to. Execution simply continues after the conditional anyway.

(I also removed the needless `&&`. Not that it should happen, but just in case the `echo` fails there's no reason not to exit.)

Comment: Thanks makes more sense after your explanation :)

Comment: +1 for not continuing and for continuing to fail on failure to fail.

Comment: I would add >&2 and exit with a non zero value

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the `continue` line which is normally used to skip to the next iteration of a `for` or `while` loop.

Therefore just removing the `else` part of  your script should allow it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Drop the `else continue`. It's entirely unneeded.