# Cygwin copy only if file already exists

Tags: cygwin

I want to copy a xml file from one remote box to a bunch of other remote boxes, but I only want it to copy the file it there is currently an existing file already in place. How can I do that?

One more question, is there a way to export out the list of  only if the file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it using regular DOS commands, there's no need to resort to `cygwin`:

```
IF EXIST filename_on_remote_server COPY /Y filename_on_local_server filename_on_remote_server
```

Or, if you are writing a `BASH` script for  `cygwin`, then you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-file-does-not-exist-in-bash).

Comment: I don't think the standard windows dos prompt supports UNC paths?

Comment: @Tony - Yes, it does. You preceed the network location with \\. For example, \\somenetworklocation\somefolder\someotherfolder. Refer to this link for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention

Comment: can't seem to get it to work it either throws The system cannot find the file specified or if I just try to CD to my remote box I get \\<box>\folder\ cmd does not support UNC paths as current directories.

Comment: @Tony - To be able to CD to the folder, you'd have to mount it as a drive. But from your original question, I'm not sure why you would need to CD to the folder. You can just execute the copy command and specify the UNC path as the destination folder. There's no need to CD to the destination.

Comment: Thanks I realized that as I was troublshooting the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about using cygwin but as it's windows you can just use `xcopy`.

```
xcopy \\remotebox1\file.xml \\remotebox2\file.xml /U /Y
```

That will copy the file only if it exists in the destination already, and will overwrite without prompting.

Answer (score 0):

This will work from inside in a bash file:

```
if [ -f /path/to/file.xml ]; then
  cp /path/to/file.xml /path/to/other/file.xml
fi
```

A one-liner for the command line might be:

```
[ -f /path/to/file.xml ] && cp /path/to/file.xml /path/to/other/file.xml
```