# How to proceed in the script if file exists ?

Tags: bash

how to proceed in the script if file exists?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start"
# waiting to be exist file
echo "file already exists, continuing"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell if a file does not exist in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-file-does-not-exist-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

Do a `while` if a `sleep X`, so that it will check the existence of the file every X seconds.

When the file will exist, the `while` will finish and you will continue with the `echo "file already exists, continuining"`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start"
### waiting to be exist file
while [ ! -f "/your/file" ]; # true if /your/file does not exist
do
  sleep 1
done
echo "file already exists, continuing"
```

---

> And goes instead of checking the file existence check if the script
>   has already completed the background?

Based on the code you posted, I did some changes to make it work completely:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
sleep 5
) &

PID=$!
echo "the pid is $PID"

while [ ! -z "$(ps -ef | awk -v p=$PID '$2==p')" ]
do
  echo "still running"
  sleep 1
done

echo "done"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! ;) And goes instead of checking the file existence check if the script has already completed the background?

Comment: Mmmm for that you can work with the PID of the process, checking if it is still present: `ps -ef | grep PID`, etc.

Comment: @VeronikaLipská check my updated answer based on your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There are OS-specific ways to perform blocking waits on the file system. Linux uses `inotify` (I forget the BSD equivalent). After installing [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki), you can write code similar to

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start"
inotifywait -e create $FILE & wait_pid=$!
if [[ -f $FILE ]]; then
    kill $wait_pid
else
    wait $wait_pid
fi
echo "file exists, continuing"
```

The call to `inotifywait` does not exit until it receives notification from the operating system that `$FILE` has been created.

---

The reason for not simply calling `inotifywait` and letting it block is that there is a race condition: the file might not exist when you test for it, but it could be created before you can start watching for the creation event. To fix that, we start a background process that waits for the file to be created, *then* check if it exists. If it does, we can kill `inotifywait` and proceed. If it does not, `inotifywait` is already watching for it, so we are guaranteed to see it be created, so we simply `wait` on the process to complete.

Comment: this doesn't work if it doesn't exist. documentation says: `create: A file or directory was created within a watched directory.` the error message i get: `Couldn't watch /tmp/.mrxvt-11843: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

To fedorqui: Is it so good? There is a problem?

```
#!/bin/bash
(
..
my code
..
) &

PID=$BASHPID or PID=$$

while [ ! ps -ef | grep $PID ]
do
  sleep 0
done
```

Thank you

Comment: You have different small issues that I solve in my code. See my updated answer.