# shell script to remove a file if it already exist

Tags: shell

I am working on some stuff where I am storing data in a file.
But each time I run the script it gets appended to the previous file.

I want help on how I can remove the file if it already exists.

Comment: [Check if the file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/638980/4009370)... and then call `rm $my_file`, right? What shell are you using?

Answer (score 424):

Don't bother checking if the file exists, just try to remove it.

```
rm -f /p/a/t/h
# or
rm /p/a/t/h 2> /dev/null
```

Note that the second command will fail (return a non-zero exit status) if the file did not exist, but the first will succeed owing to the `-f` (short for `--force`) option.  Depending on the situation, this may be an important detail.

But more likely, if you are appending to the file it is because your script is using `>>` to redirect something into the file.  Just replace `>>` with `>`.  It's hard to say since you've provided no code.

Note that you *can* do something like `test -f /p/a/t/h && rm /p/a/t/h`, but doing so is completely pointless.  It is quite possible that the test will return true but the /p/a/t/h will fail to exist before you try to remove it, or worse the test will fail and the /p/a/t/h will be created before you execute the next command which expects it to not exist.  Attempting this is a classic race condition.  Don't do it.

Comment: This isn't helpful if they need to know if it existed and was deleted.  Eating stderr doesn't provide that. Not handling the existence doesn't let you have a broader script run without failing.

Comment: @uchuugaka This is a simple solution when you don't care if a file is there, all you want is to make sure it's *not* there.

Comment: Good answers should be forthcoming and complete about the side-effects is the generalization of my message, but shell scripts frequently do want to know what is or is not found and what is or is not actioned.

Comment: `rm /p/a/t/h 2> /dev/null` won't keep the return code ( `echo $?` ) as 0 if file didn't exist. That would make Jenkins kind of jobs to fail just because we tried to delete a non existing  file.

Comment: @uchuugaka -- I've avoided responding to this comment for quite some time, but it needs to be addressed.  Checking if the file exists before you delete it is *always* a bad idea.  See the final paragraph of my answer.  There is an inherent race condition that simply cannot be avoided by doing that sort of thing.  If you do not want to overwrite an existing file, you can try some shell specific magic (like `noclobber` in bash), or maybe chmod-ing the extant file so the redirect fails if the file exists (doesn't avoid the race condition), but all that will do is make the bugs more subtle.

Comment: Oh I get the race condition concept. But why would it make sense to just eat messaging. That doesn’t seem helpful to a user reading a log. In practice not all files are subject to race conditions if they are not modifiable by anything else. Think os upgrade installer. Pretty stable state.

Comment: @uchuugaka you can do `rm -fv` and it will output a message if the file was deleted, and it will output nothing if nothing was deleted.

Answer (score 197):

Another one line command I used is:

```
[ -e file ] && rm file
```

Comment: Or alternatively: [ ! -e file ] || rm file     . This version returns 0 instead of some error.

Comment: @nawfelbgh Thanks, this is great for chaining in a longer script.

Comment: For those not very observant, like myself, there is a space between the left bracket and the exclamation mark, which is necessary for the command to work

Comment: This answer is flawed as it might error due to a race condition between checking for and actually removing the file. See William’s answer for details.

Comment: I guess this line is saying something like "if the file doesn't exist then remove it". But what is `-e` in bash? "exists"?

Answer (score 195):

You can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="file_you_want_to_delete"

if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    rm "$file"
fi
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: Simple and easy to read and also ensures that `echo $?` doesn't give 1 if file doesn't exist.

Comment: If needed, you can also do this as a one-liner, see my answer below.

Comment: Shouldn't you quote `"$file"`?

Comment: If you want to deal with weirdly named files, then yes, it is safe to quote. But for the sake of simplicity, I'd rather leave the answer as is.

Comment: @JindraHelcl so you are providing an inherently wrong answer. :(

Answer (score 120):

If you want to ignore the step to check if file exists or not, then you can use a fairly easy command, which will delete the file if exists and does not throw an error if it is non-existing.

```
 rm -f xyz.csv
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of part of the highest rated answer, from 2015.

Comment: the main answer didn't explain that with the `-f` it wouldn't throw an error. This answer helped me, thank you.

Comment: Agree with Doug although this seems like a good use case for a wiki-like edit of a response.

Answer (score 46):

A one liner shell script to remove a file if it already exist (based on Jindra Helcl's answer):

`[ -f file ] && rm file`

or with a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/path/to/file.ext"
[ -f $file ] && rm $file
```

Answer (score 17):

Something like this would work

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -fe FILE ]
then 
    rm FILE
fi
```

-f checks if it's a regular file

-e checks if the file exist

> [Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) for more information

**EDIT :** -e used with -f is redundant, fo using -f alone should work too

Comment: `-a` is deprecated, use `-e` instead.

Comment: this will throw errors on directories or links or other non-normal files. It is imho better/safer to use `-f`.

Comment: ok. still, the `-e` in `-fe` is redundant, as `-f` also checks the existence of the file as far as I know..

Comment: If I edit, I'll just make a duplicate out of your answer, but I will precise it

Comment: For whatever reason, I can get this to work with -e and -f, but -fe gives me "urnary operator expected". Even after quoting my variables or switching to bash and double-bracketing.

Answer (score 8):

So in my case I wanted to remove a FIFO file before I create it again, so this worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/tmp/test"
rm -rf $file | true
mkfifo $file
```

`| true` will continue the script even if file is not found.

Answer (score 4):

`if [ $( ls <file> ) ]; then rm <file>; fi`

Also, if you redirect your output with `>` instead of `>>` it will overwrite the previous file

Comment: this is not a one-liner, sorry but the @liwp_Stephen one is that.

Comment: Even if properly quoted, this breaks if `file` is something like `5 -lt 2`