# Is possible use the deploy connection to move files or another actions?

Tags: azure-devops

I have my pipeline to publish my code in an own server and works good, but now i would like do more actions like move differents files o delete them using the deploy group, is possible?

I don't know if I'm wrong, but i don't want open the server using a new connection through SSH.

Thanks for all!

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible use the deploy connection to move files or another actions?

I suppose you are have the connection through SSH to deploy your code to your server.

To more actions like move different files o delete them, you can try to use the [SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops), select the SSH service connection you deployed:

Then delete/remove the file with shell command, like:

```
file="file_you_want_to_delete"

if [ -f $file ] ; then
    rm $file
fi
```

Code from: [shell script to remove a file if it already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318068/shell-script-to-remove-a-file-if-it-already-exist).

Alternatively, you can use the [Remote delete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saeidbabaei.remotedeletesaeid) task to move files, which you can just provide:

- Enter Remote Computer IP address
- Enter User name and password for remote machine

Hope this helps.