# Trigger a command if a file gets deleted in linux

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Let's say I have a file `/local/content/en/abc.html` and I have a same file in `/local/en/abc.html`. I want to add a watcher to `/local` so that if `/local/content/en/abc.html`gets deleted, it automatically deletes the `/local/en/abc.html`file.

How can I achieve this? I have a Linux environment. This can be a bash file which would be watching`/local` directory.

Comment: It seems like it should just be a simple `if` statement. It tests if one file exists, and if not it deletes the other file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell if a regular file does not exist in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash)

Comment: Looks like a good use case for `rsync --delete`

Comment: @Shauzab. Do they have the same content (/local/content/en/abc.html and /local/en/abc.html) ?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/939600/how-to-get-notified-when-a-specific-file-is-deleted-in-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a job for `inotify` which is built into the Linux kernel. This is a subsystem that lets you watch specific folders for a change and receive notifications if/when that happens. It is typically used to automatically update directory views, reload configuration files, log changes, backup, synchronize, etc.

`inotify` itself is an API, not a program. You can find more info on the API from the `inotify` man page if you want to write a small program yourself, or check out the GitHub link for a tool which lets you easily set up an inotify watch from a shell script (where you can take appropriate action when the notification comes in).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools

Comment: please try not just post links but give a sufficient answer to this specific question

Comment: @loki edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same content, you could use a symbolic link (ln -s).
For example :

```
$echo Test > a
$ln -s a b
$ ll
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ...................... a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ...................... b -> a
```

The files a and b have the same content :

```
$ cat b
Test
```

If you destroy a, b is only a symbolic link:

```
$rm b
$cat b
cat: b: no file
```

After the creation of the file a, you can use again the file b :

```
$echo Test > a
$ cat b
Test
```