# How to execute a command based on file availability?

Tags: linux

I am very new to Shell Scripting. I have a directory, say "Input".
Once in a while, a file(let's say test.csv) comes to this directory(Using SFTP).

I want to execute another command based on the file availability.

For example,
whenever the "Input" directory contains the test.csv file, a curl command needs to be executed and the file will be moved to a archive directory. The process should be always running in production.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jee

Comment: Please show your effort.  Please take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash

Comment: Hi Codeforester, Thanks for your reply. I know how to check a file exists or not. But, how to make the script to run forever? Do we need to schedule the script(using crontab) or is there any other way?