# What does -f (minus f) do in the Laravel Forge deploy script?

Tags: laravel, sh

Here's the code snippet:

```
if [ -f artisan ]
then
   php artisan migrate --force
fi
```

What does the `-f` do in the if statement?  Is is asking whether the batch file was invoked with artisan as a parameter?  Or perhaps checking to see that the `artisan` file is found in the current directory?  How exactly does it work?

Comment: `man test` is what you are looking for

Comment: `if [ -f artisan ] = if artisan file exists then go on` [Check more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21164441/741747).

Comment: …or [`man [`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/coreutils/[.1.en.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell if a file does not exist in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-file-does-not-exist-in-bash)

Answer (score -1):

If the file *artisan* exists, then go on doing the migration.

Credit @the-alpha who wrote this as an comment