# how can i check if file exists in bash script?

Tags: bash

How can I check if the file exists. I tried something with the until loop but I couldn't, it's not working properly. What I want to do is to have the file I specified in a folder. If not, I want it to go into an infinite loop. exit the loop if it exists

I leave the code I tried below

```
while ! find /mnt/c -name 'file*.msixbundle' 1> /dev/null 2>&1
do
echo "file not found"
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell if a regular file does not exist in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash)

Comment: The loop does not make sense. Unless some magic process creates the file during the loop, the `find` command will always produce the same exit code. Aside from this, you can't derive from the exit status of `find`, whether a file was found.

Comment: @user1934428 He/she''s guessing syntax.

Comment: @Grau At least insert a sleep command in between loops if you deliberately want to do that and fry either your CPU or your storage. Relying on inotify is a better solution.

Comment: I've already asked because I want to use a while loop instead of if, but I guess the moderator says you should do it with if.  If I wanted to do it with if, I wouldn't have asked my question anyway.  it is a sad situation.